# Lightning vs JS/CSS frameworks

Tags: visualforce, lightning

We have dabbled with Lightning in our sandboxes and to be honest we are not that motivated to switch to Lightning as we honestly believe the bugs/issues of Lightning is quite clumsy.

Instead of using Lightning to beef up our users UX, we have adopted Visual Force /Boostrap/jQuery to provide a much better experience something like this (not our exact solution ofc)

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

My point being what is the need/impetus to redesign the UX from Visualforce to Lightning when I can provide a much better UI/UX with Visualforce/JS/CSS frameworks.

Or in a much simple words.."**What are we missing by not designing our UX/UI in Lightning but beefing up our UI/UX with latest CSS/JS frameworks/libraries coupled with Visualforce ?**"

Comment: Not sure its a question of "what are we missing out on when using visualforce" but rather, when to use which, this is described at [Visualforce & Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce) and you can also refer to the [Lightning FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ)